# How to use a custom components folder in a Gatsby project?

Tags: reactjs, components, material-ui, gatsby

I want to add some custom components made in react from a GitHub repository to my Gatsby project, but I don't know how to add an external folder.
The components folder I want to add follows this composition:

```
|-- /dist
    |-- /components
    |-- /modules
    |-- index.js
    |-- link.js
    |-- package.json
    |-- semantics.js
    |-- style.js
|-- /i18n
|-- /src
    |-- /components
    |-- /modules
    |-- index.js
    |-- semantics.js
    |-- styles.js
|-- /stories
|-- /trans
|-- build.js
|-- core
|-- icons
|-- link.js
|-- package.json
|-- package-lock.json
```

Any idea on how to add the folder to the project?

Comment: Did you try just placing the folder in your project? Is the github repo available as an npm package so you can import it with `npm install that-package`?

Answer (score 1):

To use custom directories simply place the folder in your Gatsby project and add it to package.json like: `"material-components": "../material-components/dist",` (this is how it looks for my particular case).